# Unable to connect with S3 and Spark Locally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

Below is my code :
I am trying to access s3 files from spark locally.
But getting error :
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://bucketname/folder
I am also using jars :hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar while submitting spark job from cmd.

```
package org.test.snow
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

object SnowS3 {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IDV4")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import spark.implicits._
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", "A*******************A")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey","A********************A")
val cus_1=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.load("s3a://tb-us-east/working/customer.csv")
cus_1.show()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
FYI: I am using spark 2.1

Comment: are you able to access `s3a://tb-us-east/working/customer.csv` using aws cli using the same credentials?

Comment: @Michael West Actually I  am confused. How can I test this in aws cli ?meaning I need I should have EMR to test the spark code ..right?

Comment: I meant testing the s3 access of your aws credentials.  If it is a credentials issue then there may be no code issue.

Comment: No no I am able to connect to snow flake using that credentials. There is no problem with credentials .

Comment: I am able to run this code from EMR cluster but not locally .. No idea why :(

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set that fs.s3a.impl option; that's a superstition which seems to persist in spark examples.

Instead uses the S3A connector just by using the s3a:// prefix with

- consistent versions of hadoop-* jar versions. Yes, hadoop-aws-2.7.3 needs hadoop-common-2.7.3
- setting the s3a specific authentication options, `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key'

If that doesn't work, look at the [s3a troubleshooting docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html)